# Undefined index for uploading image on server iOS

Tags: php, ios, nsdata, image-uploading

I am trying to upload image on server and I receive unexpected response from server.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    NSString *urlstring=[NSString stringWithFormat:USER_IMAGE_UPLOAD_URL_STRING];

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    int userId = self.request.userId;
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",userId];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:userId] forKey:@"userid"];
    [dictionary setObject:SITE_NAME forKey:@"site"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager POST:urlstring parameters:dictionary constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"profile_image" fileName:imageName mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //My Code to parse response
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        //failure
        [self callTarget:self.request.delegate Selector:self.request.failureSelector WithObject:SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG_MSG];
    }];
```

In response I get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: site in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.de/httpdocs/api/profile_image.php on line 14
{"status":"error","message":"No profile_image provided."}
```

Comment: Check your server. May be you are using `$_GET` rather than `$_POST`. Also post your server code.

Comment: Yogesh is right, seems like a server issue.

Comment: I am using post to upload

Comment: I feel sorry but can't access server code.

Comment: @iBug If you can't access your server than contact your server admin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
```

Hope this helps.. :)